# Accessing inner JS objects With Typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

Suppose I have the following dataset of

```
data = {
    result: [
      {
            id: '001',
            name: 'Caio B',
            address: {
                address: 'sau paulo',
                city: 'sau paulo',
                country: 'brazil',
            },
        },
          {
            id: '002',
            name: 'Gustavo H',
            address: {
                address: 'Rio',
                city: 'Rio',
                country: 'brazil',
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

Which I would like to extract only the country from the address object, and combine it with the id and name so the converted result would look as follows:

```
data = {
    result: [
      {
            id: '001',
            name: 'Caio B'
            country: 'brazil',
        },
          {
            id: '002',
            name: 'Gustavo H',
            country: 'brazil',
        },
    ],
}
```

how can I achieve this in Typescript using minimal processing ?

Comment: I want to know that where you want to use it at html or in ts class?

Comment: Learn how to do it with normal javascript before typescript.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a OOP lover
create a class for Country in ts

```
class Country{
 public id:string = '';
  public name:string = '';
  public country:string = '';
constructor(I){
  this.id = I.id;
  this.name =I.name;
  this.country =I.address.country;
  }
}
```

now use a for loop for your Input data

```
public Countries:Array<Country> =[];
```

in a function where you receive data

```
for(let i = 0; i< data.length;i++)
 this.Countries.push(new Country(data[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using plain JavaScript. Iterate the items and filter out the properties you don't need. Something like this:

```js
 function process(items) {
      var data = {};
      data.result = items.map(function (item) {
       return {
         id: item.id,
          name: item.name,
          country: item.address.country
        }
      })
      return data;
    }
    var data = {
    "result": [
     {
      "id": "001",
      "name": "Caio B",
      "address": {
        "address": "sau paulo",
        "city": "sau paulo",
        "country": "brazil"
     }
    },
    {
      "id": "002",
      "name": "Gustavo H",
      "address": {
        "address": "Rio",
        "city": "Rio",
        "country": "brazil"
      }
    }
   ]
 };
 
var data2 = process(data.result);
    console.log(data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

For each result, assign country and remove address:

```js
data = {
  result: [{
      id: '001',
      name: 'Caio B',
      address: {
        address: 'sau paulo',
        city: 'sau paulo',
        country: 'brazil',
      },
    },
    {
      id: '002',
      name: 'Gustavo H',
      address: {
        address: 'Rio',
        city: 'Rio',
        country: 'brazil',
      },
    },
  ],
}

data.result.forEach(o => { o['country'] = o.address.country; delete o.address })

console.log(data)
```